# Kubernetes can not list pods as user

Tags: kubernetes

I am seeing this error for user `jenkins` when deploying.

```
Error: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ci:jenkins" cannot list pods in the namespace "kube-system"
```

I have created a definition for service account

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
```

I have created a ClusterRoleBinding

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: kube-system
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a namespace (in the ServiceAccount creation) you will automatically create it in the `default` namespace. The same with a Role (which is always a one-namespace resource).

What you need to do is to create a ClusterRole with the correct permissions (basically just change your role into a ClusterRole) and then set the correct namespace either on the ServiceAccount resource or in the ClusterRole binding.

You can also skip creating the Role and RoleBinding, as the ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding will override it either way.

--

With that said. It's always good practice to create a specific ServiceAccount and RoleBinding per namespace when it comes to deploys, so that you don't accidently create an admin account which is used in a remote CI tool like... Jenkins ;)